# How can I get in Facebook Ad Types?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, reporting

How can I get in Facebook API reports some indications for the type of the ad? 
for example Sponsored Stories, Traditional Ads.. etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the Facebook Ads API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/